# Going downhill - what's the constraint force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

We are going downhill on a path $$y=a(1-x^2),$$ and I need to calculate the constraint force-position function. What I've done is this:

The lagrangian of the system is $$L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)-mgy+\lambda(t)(y-a(1-x^2)),$$ so the 2 equation are $$m\ddot{x}=2a\lambda x$$ and $$m\ddot{y}=-mg+\lambda.$$ Based on the equations, the constraint force is $F_y=\lambda$ and $F_x=2a\lambda x$, but I can't calculate the value of $\lambda.$ How should I do it?

Comment: Why not just find the normal force?

Comment: Isn't the constraint force just the normal force?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy I think it is. But how would you calculate it?

Comment: You have 2 equations for 3 unknowns. If you take the second time derivative of the constraint equation , you get one more equation to solve your problem

Comment: Hints: 1. First solve for $x$: Energy conservation yields $E/m = (1+ (2ax)^2)\dot{x}^2/2+ga(1-x^2).$ What are the initial conditions? 2. Next solve for $y$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).